# How list my posts in wordpress with next page of posts

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

What Wordpress function or approach is needed for creating this kind of pagination?

[image: blogs]
[image: my goal]

Comment: it's called "pagination".

Comment: how to I do that, can you provide an example or smth?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your code base? Are you working on your own WordPress template or simply asking for configuration help? We need more input.

Comment: I'm just templating and trying to learn some stuff to see how does it work, right now I'm trying to make a custom theme for wordpress with all custom stuff...even if the index.php is a php file its written in the html, linked with <?php bloginfo(template_uri();)/js/main.js ?> and stuff like that, soo I want to know how to do this pagination...

Comment: You can go to `search.php` file and check the code of the pagination working. Also, i strongly recommend you to read more about paginations here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Yeah I did read this but, I didn't knew that this is called pagination and I'm sorry for the bad english and my way of expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `search.php` file and check the code of the pagination working. That part below:

```
        // Previous/next page navigation.
        the_posts_pagination( array(
            'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
            'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
        ) );
```

Also, i strongly recommend you to read more about paginations here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

Comment: Read the examples and try it. If you have any problem with your code, come back here, update the question with the code and we will be able to help you more.

Comment: I did it, it works just fine... I just didn't know that this is called pagination, I learn fast soo...